# StackOverflowError being caused by a TableModelListener

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm not sure why this is recursing.

```
jTable1.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

 public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent evt) {
  int sum = 0;
  int i=0;
  for (i =0 ; i<2; i++){
   sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(jTable1.getValueAt(0, i).toString());
  }
  jTable1.setValueAt(sum, 0, 2);
 }

});
```

The exception is: (it keeps repeating)

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:277)
        at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(JTable.java:2553)
        at javax.swing.JTable.getValueAt(JTable.java:2695)
        at testprogram.guitest.TestTableModel$1.tableChanged(TestTableModel.java:63)
        at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableChanged(AbstractTableModel.java:280)
        at javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel.fireTableCellUpdated(AbstractTableModel.java:259)
        at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:650)
        at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:2719)
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JTable.setValueAt causes a tablechanged event to fire, so you're calling the event handler repeatedly from within the event handler.  Set the value in the model, not in the table.

Comment: I know this is old, but wanted to point out this does not fix the issue because the table model is changed whether the table's setValueAt method or the model's setValueAt method is used. @jaime's answer should at least be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

From the event handler (tableChanged method) wrap your code that makes use of setValue method with code to remove and add the listener, like this

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
model.removeTableModelListener(this);
// YOUR CODE WITH setValueAt calls begins here
if (ppt == null || cantidad > ppt.getStock()) {

model.setValueAt(ppt != null ? ppt.getStock() : 0, e.getFirstRow(), 3);
}

model.setValueAt(precioUnitario * cantidad, e.getFirstRow(), 4);

// YOUR CODE with setValueAt calls ends here
model.addTableModelListener(this);
}
```

This will disable temporarily the listener while you work on validations.

Comment: Wow this works like magic. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're updating a value in an event handler for updates. This will naturally trigger the event handler to be called again. Which will trigger the event handler to be called again, etc.

You'd need to perhaps remove the listener before making the update.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem earlier when using `jlist`. My solution was to simply change the sequence of my lines of code.

1. Get all the `jpanel`s which have images.
2. Add a listener just before adding `object[]` to `jlist`

The issue I previously had (which was creating a `stack-overflow error` was adding the listener to `jlist` first, *then* getting all of the `jpanel`s with images.